# Confused with a game engine definition

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to game developing , I already built a game with SDL/C,Canvas/Js .. all 2D
Now I want to learn 3D games everybody tell me to use an engine , My problems are:

- What's an engine, is it like Unity,UDK.. or like OpenGL,DirectX.. because I found both answers which is which ?
- How can I make something like OpenGL/SDL I used C but I never knew how to manipulate screen's pixel and low-level stuff? (I just need an idea how to communicate with graphic card and how it works not asking for assembly code or similar)
- Can you recommend any book that explains how to work with
  OpenGL/C++,importing objects, animations etc..

Comment: read this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine

Answer (score 3):

The graphical layer (DirectX, OpenGL, etc) is one component of a game engine.  Obviously objects need to be drawn to the screen, but the engine is more than that.  It defines data structures and functions/operations commonly used to build a certain type of game.  It lays down the foundation for you so that you can focus on implementing those features which are specific to your game.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGl and DirectX are APIs where you dictate each step to render your graphics.

Unity and UDK are game engines - taking care of much of the more low-level functionality so you don't have to write it yourself. This allows you to focus more on gameplay while it takes care of much of the graphics manipulation behind the scenes.

The game engine will use the graphics APIs in addition to many other tasks in order to help you streamline development.

Answer (score 1):

A game engine is a development framework for developing games. Unity and UDK are game engines. OpenGL and DirectX are rendering engine. A game engine may have its own rendering engine.

[Game Engine Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135) by Jason Gregory is a nice book